# how to solve the error due to default value declaration of array in a function

Tags: c++

Imade a fibonacci series calculator(`fibo`) but it causesan error

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct numtag
{
    unsigned long num;
    char tag[60];
};

char *primality(const unsigned long,unsigned long i=0);
numtag *fiboPrime(const unsigned long,unsigned long i=0,numtag fibo[]={{0,primality(0)},{1,primality(1)}});



int main(){};

char *primality(unsigned long p,unsigned long i)
{
    if(p<=1)
        return "NEITHER PRIME NOR COMPOSITE";
    else if(p==2||p==3)
        return "\tPRIME";
    else if(p%2==0||p%3==0)
        return "\tCOMPOSITE";
    else if(n<5)
        i=5;
    if(i*i<=p)
        if(p%i==0||p%(i+2)==0)
            return "\tCOMPOSITE";
        else
            return primality(p,i+6);
    else
        return "\tPRIME";
};
numtag *fiboPrime(unsigned long n,unsigned long i,numtag *fibo){//I need to figure this out};
```

It produces an error:
`[Error] could not convert '{{0, primality(0, 5)}, {1, primality(1, 5)}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'numtag*'`

Please Help Me

Comment: C-arrays cannot be copied, use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: C-strings literal are `const char[N]`, so return `const char*` instead of `char*`.

Comment: Its not due to string literals/ It is due to numtag array in function fiboPrime

Comment: You cannot initialize `tag` array through `char*`. Just do as Jarod42 says.

Comment: I cannot initialize array in function declaration. Even int array is not working